# IHow to get value of original value of hashcode

Tags: java, hashcode

I have the hashcode of a string, and now I want to get the original string back. Is there any method available for this?

Comment: Hashcodes are not even guaranteed to be unique I believe.

Comment: I have some difficulty to understand the question. Do you want to convert a hashcode into it's original string? This would not be possible since a hashcode value is not guaranteed to be unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such method. The hash function is lossy.

When you think about it, the set of all possible strings is *much* larger than the set of all possible ints, making a two-way mapping impossible.

If it were possible to recover the string from its hash code, that would enable one to compress an arbitrary amount of data into a single `int`, and then to be able to perfectly reconstruct it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `string` to `hashcode` is not a `bijection`. While a string has only one hashcode (given a function), there is an infinite amount of string which have a hascode value.